# Run a yeoman sub-generator using yeoman-environment

Tags: yeoman

I am having trouble running a sub-generator when yeoman is run in embedded form.

The documentation for [integrating yeoman in other tools](http://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html) provides this example:

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-environment');
var env = yeoman.createEnv();
env.register(require.resolve('generator-mine'), 'mine:app');
env.run('mine:app', done);
```

This works for my generator `mine`, too.
However, when I try to use the same code to run any sub-generator (`mine:client`), it does not work correctly. There are two failure modes.

First, if I only register the app generator, and try to run the sub-generator:

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-environment');
var env = yeoman.createEnv();
env.register(require.resolve('generator-mine'), 'mine:app');
env.run('mine:client', done);
```

I get:

```
You don't seem to have a generator with the name “mine:client” installed.
```

Second, if I register both the app and sub-generator, and try to run the sub-generator:

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-environment');
var env = yeoman.createEnv();
env.register(require.resolve('generator-mine'), 'mine:app');
env.register(require.resolve('generator-mine'), 'mine:client');
env.run('mine:client', done);
```

Then there is no error message. However, the `mine:app` generator is run instead of the desired `mine:client` generator.

Keep in mind that the sub-generator works as expected when invoked directly from the shell.

What am I missing?

Comment: how did you run this file ? how did you put this into bin runnable file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`env.register()` doesn't search the yeoman generator-XXX for all `generators/*/index.js` it only uses the `main:` entry from the `package.json`.

`env.lookup()` scans the node install for generator-* and registers all generators it finds.

Change

`env.register(require.resolve('generator-mine'), 'mine:client');`

To

```
env.lookup(() => {  folder
  env.run('mine:client', {}, err => { console.log('done'); });
});
```